# "Do like readlines()" to a Session object (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to pick out a few lines of information from some webpages.  I want (or I am) to open the web pages, iterate down through the lines, checking each for a keyword, copying the information I want when I find it.

The pages require a session.

```
def getpage()
    home = 'website'
    exstension1 = '/input/page'
    extension2 = '/output/page'
    indexnumber = '11100'

    sess = requests.Session()
    getter = sess.get(home+extension1)
    payload = {'foo':'bar','indexnumber':indexnumber}
    getter = sess.post(home+extension2,data=payload)

    return sess
```

As I tried to say in the title, I need a readlines() method for a .get()

```
a.get(somePage)###Now could I put...###.readlines()
####or
a.get(somePage).text.readlines()###?
###I don't think I want the following, for performance reasons, correct me if I am wrong
F = open(someNewFile,mode='w')
F.write(a.get(somePage).text)
F.close()
F = open(thatFileIJustMade).readlines()###All that just to turn it into a File on which I can use readlines?
```

thanks

When I try

```
a.get(somePage).readlines()
```

I get

```
AttributeError: Response Object Doesn't have attribute readlines
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, but the most Requests-y way is to use a streaming request along with `Response.iter_lines()`:

```
r = requests.get(somePage, stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines(1024):
    # Do stuff on this line.
```

Answer (score 4):

Beyond @Lukasa's excellent and entirely correct way of doing this, you could also do:

```
import io

r = requests.get(some_page)
file_like_obj = io.StringIO(r.text)
lines = file_like_obj.readlines()
```

Note that `r.text` is absolutely the right attribute to use on the Response object because on Python2 it will require unicode and on Python 3 a native string (which is unicode by default).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, keep in mind:

Warning

> iter_lines() is not reentrant safe. Calling this method multiple times >causes some of the received data being lost. In case you need to call it >from multiple places, use the resulting iterator object instead:

```
lines = r.iter_lines()
# Save the first line for later or just skip it

first_line = next(lines)

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

For the sake of simplicity, I use the following approach:

```
r = requests.get(somePage).text
r_lines = r.split("\n")

for line in r_lines:
    #line logic goes here
```